# how to make in css my font family work sans?

Tags: html, css, fonts, html-helper, helper

*I want to make my font family in CSS : work sans*
how can I make it
my code :
`<h4 style="color : white ; font-family :work sans; font-size:14px;">hello word</h4>`

Answer (score 0):

You can define the following selectors in order to achieve the styling for the h4 element you asked.

The whole code is available in [codepen](https://codepen.io/yonatangross/pen/bGwVKBY):

or append the following selector for the h4 element in your css file:

```
 h4 {
  color: white;
  font-family: work sans;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```